# Getting help on matching modules in Zeppelin/Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-zeppelin

We're setting up a new Zeppelin 0.10.0 environment running Python 3.7.  I'm new to Zeppelin and fairly new to Python and I want to see what modules are already loaded.  I start off asking for help:

```
%livy.pyspark
help()
```

I get a response:

> ... less relevant text omitted...
> To get a list of available modules, keywords, symbols, or topics,
> type "modules", "keywords", "symbols", or "topics".  Each module also
> comes with a one-line summary of what it does; to list the modules
> whose name or summary contain a given string such as "spam", type
> "modules spam".
>
> help>  You are now leaving help and returning to the Python
> interpreter. If you want to ask for help on a particular object
> directly from the interpreter, you can type "help(object)".  Executing
> "help('string')" has the same effect as typing a particular string at
> the help> prompt.

Then I create a note with the following:

```
%livy.pyspark
help('modules')
```

I get a long list of modules.  Among them is one named "urllib".

> Please wait a moment while I gather a list of all available modules...
> (many modules) Enter any module name to get more help.  Or, type
> "modules spam" to search for modules whose name or summary contain the
> string "spam".

At this point I decide I'd like to find all modules containing the string "url".  I can't manage it.  Below are the things I've tried, and the error messages I've gotten.  What do I need to do to get this seemingly simple request to work?

```
%livy.pyspark
modules url

invalid syntax (<stdin>, line 2)
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    modules url
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I guess that was because I wasn't within the help system.

```
%livy.pyspark
help('modules url')

'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/_sitebuiltins.py", line 103, in __call__
    return pydoc.help(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pydoc.py", line 1891, in __call__
    self.help(request)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pydoc.py", line 1940, in help
    self.listmodules(request.split()[1])
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pydoc.py", line 2076, in listmodules
    apropos(key)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pydoc.py", line 2170, in apropos
    ModuleScanner().run(callback, key, onerror=onerror)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pydoc.py", line 2131, in run
    loader = spec.loader
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'
```

That error message is cryptic to this noob.

```
%livy.pyspark
help('url')

No Python documentation found for 'url'.
Use help() to get the interactive help utility.
Use help(str) for help on the str class.
```

Well, that makes sense.  There is no `url` command, but I thought I would give it a try anyway.